# Magento "place order" redirection for payment gateway

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.5

this is my first actual post on StackOverflow. I'm on here quite often because you guys always solve my queries!

We have a problem in a checkout cart on a Magento on localhost.

We have Magento version 1.5 and are using the direcpay payment module(Created the module manually by using   [**the blog by roi smikes**](http://roysimkes.net/blog/2009/11/creating-your-own-payment-gateway-for-magento-part-1/)).

The problem appears when a customer adds products to their cart . When they click on the '**Place Order**' button, they should be taken to a form in which the user have to enter customer detail field before redirecting to payment gateway like merchantid,name and address etc, in which they can send these information through url to the direcpay payment gateway.I dont know what to do next,should i have to make a new form in which these information should be entered and how the place order button can be handle.

Any help/advice/solution/anything! would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi All,

I successfully added a new payment module.

I now need to pass values to the external gateway, however I am unable to figure what files to modify and what code to add to achieve this.

I need to send the amount, order id and a bunch of other values to an external URL when I click Place Order.

I have been struggling for 2 days, please help!!!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you desire is as below

```
Click Place order ---> Customer Details Page -----> External payment gateway
```

Steps to achieve this

1. modifty saveOrderAction() in the file     app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

add this file code which checks what payment method was selected

```
    if($data['method']=='cashondelivery')
    {
        $redirectUrl='';
    }
    else
    {
        $redirectUrl = 'https://mysite.com/customer_details.php';
    }
```

1. Add a proceed button in the customer_details.php page which now takes customer to bank website with the posted information